# Strange message: xcodebuild[14933:1513031] DVTPortal: Service - on tns run ios

Tags: ios, mobile, nativescript

on

```
$tns run ios
```

I have this interesting bit saying that my session expired, why is that if I am not using as I am aware anything from developerservices2.apple.com ?

```
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 6 total pods installed.
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Building project...
Xcode build...
2020-02-25 17:25:15.195 xcodebuild[14933:1513031]  DVTPortal: Service '<DVTPortalViewDeveloperService: 0x7ff1dad949c0; action='viewDeveloper'>' encountered an unexpected result code from the portal ('1100')
2020-02-25 17:25:15.195 xcodebuild[14933:1513031]  DVTPortal: Error:
Error Domain=DVTPortalServiceErrorDomain Code=1100 "Your session has expired.  Please log in." UserInfo={payload={
    creationTimestamp = "2020-02-25T17:25:15Z";
    httpCode = 200;
    protocolVersion = QH65B2;
    requestUrl = "https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/viewDeveloper.action";
    responseId = "2db7642e-2968-41e4-b622-a343370951c9";
    resultCode = 1100;
    resultString = "Your session has expired.  Please log in.";
    userLocale = "en_US";
    userString = "Your session has expired.  Please log in.";
}, NSLocalizedDescription=Your session has expired.  Please log in.}
2020-02-25 17:25:15.597 xcodebuild[14933:1513031]  DVTPortal: Service '<DVTPortalViewDeveloperService: 0x7ff1dabb4480; action='viewDeveloper'>' encountered an unexpected result code from the portal ('1100')
2020-02-25 17:25:15.597 xcodebuild[14933:1513031]  DVTPortal: Error:
Error Domain=DVTPortalServiceErrorDomain Code=1100 "Your session has expired.  Please log in." UserInfo={payload={
    creationTimestamp = "2020-02-25T17:25:15Z";
    httpCode = 200;
    protocolVersion = QH65B2;
    requestUrl = "https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/viewDeveloper.action";
    responseId = "214edf34-9ad8-471c-8207-fd361198ad8f";
    resultCode = 1100;
    resultString = "Your session has expired.  Please log in.";
    userLocale = "en_US";
    userString = "Your session has expired.  Please log in.";
}, NSLocalizedDescription=Your session has expired.  Please log in.}
Xcode build...
```

Comment: Are you trying to run on a device?

Comment: yes, iOS device is plugged into my laptop.

Comment: Have you configured your certificates / provisional profiles locally Or you let it pick from developer portal?

Comment: Was there any resolution to this?  I'm running into the same issue now., but only when I run in fastlane.

Answer (score 5):

In case somebody is running into this problem and found this question (like I did today) the root cause of the issue could be xcode, for me when running fastlane, my session in xcode was expired.

Going into `Xcode -> settings -> accounts`, my account had a little red x underneath it, logging back in fixed the issue for me

For me, I was building a react native app with EAS build locally, but the issue was in xcode when running fastlane so the solution should be applicable to other scenarios

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have successfully installed the necessary dependencies for my project using CocoaPods, with a total of 6 pods installed. The project has been successfully prepared for iOS.

However, during the Xcode build process, an error occurred related to the Apple Developer Portal. The error message states that my session has expired, and I need to log in again. This error is likely related to my  Apple Developer account credentials in Xcode.

To resolve this issue, I followed these steps:

Opened Xcode.
Went to Xcode's menu bar and click on "Xcode" > "Preferences."
Navigated to the "Accounts" tab.
Found my Apple Developer account in the list, and clicked on it.
A warning icon or an "expired" message? Sure - clicked on the "Details" button.
Clicked on the "Sign In" button to re-authenticate your account.
After re-authenticating my account, I was able to build my project without encountering the session expiration error. If the issue persists, I may want to try removing My account from Xcode and adding it again.